# How to indicate the packages those don't need export/import using bnd API

Tags: osgi, bnd

i am an fresh man in osgi,and i wonder how to indicate the packages those don't need export/import using bnd API

Comment: Don't down vote new users, especially without advising why.  It's mean and cowardly.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't export them. All packages inside your bundle that are not explicitly exported with `Export-Package` are implicitly private.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i am coding for a maven plugin and i want to use bnd api to analyze the non-osgi jar,but i can't find how to do this.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. The Maven bundle plugin already uses bnd internally so it will analyse the contents of the JAR for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try as you said